# Find Domain of a function before Simplifying?

Tags: functions

So I have this equation/function.
$Ln \dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{x^2}(x^2-16)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

My Question is, is it possible to find domain before simplifying it, and if so, would it differ from the domains I get after simplifying and getting the different $ln$ functions.

Comment: Formatting tip: use `$\ln$` instead of `ln` to format the logarithm operator correctly - for example $\ln x$ is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the log has to be defined and positive. It is defined for all $x$, and clearly it is positive if and only if $x^2>16$, i. e. $\;\lvert x\rvert >4$.

Comment: So, $(4, \infty)$ would satisfy this argument?

Comment: Add the symmetric interval, since it's an even function.

Comment: I do not know what this is, is it this- $(-\infty, -4)$ U $(4, \infty)$ ?

Comment: It's exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what happens after you simplify it - this function has one domain and it has to be determined before doing anything so you don't get confused. The domain doesn't change. For instance the function $ f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ has domain $ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} $, even though everywhere except $ x=0 $ it equals $ 1 $